# How to shuffle a range but prevent refresh?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Extract a specified range based on user input in a cell using the arrayformula
2. Shuffle/randomise that extracted range

I have tried several approaches such as a combination of sort and randarray.

However, those always refresh and therefore reshuffle as soon as I check a checkbox in that row which I also need to perform an action with conditional formatting.

Does anyone know how I could solve this challenge?

Essentially I need a randomisation method that doesn't refresh unless the user changes the input in a specified cell.

Comment: Use a script based solution instead of something based on spreadsheet functions.

Comment: I would suggest you [edit] your question with a minimal reproducible example including the formula and some sample data in markdown.  Whether script or non-script will be clearer with a better explanation of the problem space.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the range to shuffle is in `A2:C`, put this formula in cell `H2`:

```
=let( 
  refresh, H1, 
  freeze_, lambda(_, _), 
  randomNumbers_, lambda(r, c, randarray(r, c)), 
  freeze_(randomNumbers_(999, 1)) 
)
```

...and this formula in cell `J2`:

```
=sort( 
  filter(A2:C, len(B2:B)), 
  filter(H2:H, len(B2:B)), 
  true 
)
```

To reshuffle the results, select cell `H1`, choose **Insert > Checkbox**, and toggle the checkbox.

You can hide column `H` if it gets in the way.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too.